# Math operations individual elements in 2D Array - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, math, swift3, operation

I’m trying to perform different mathematical operations on individual elements of a 2D array (testArray) combined with 1D array (mod). I’ve got the following for generating individual variables but can’t figure out how to get these values back into a new 2D array. Swift 3.0.2.

```
let testArray: [[Double]] =
    [[0,100,20.1],
     [1,99,19.2],
     [3,98,18.2],
     [5,97,17.3],
     [7,96,16.4],
     [9,95,15.5]]

let mod: [Double] = [0,5,7,14,20,22]

//Math operations on the two above arrays
for var x in 0..<testArray.count {
    var result1 = Double(testArray[x][0])
    var result2 = Double(testArray[x][1] + mod[x])
    var result3 = Double(testArray[x][2] - mod[x])
    print(result1,result2,result3)
}

//output is as follows:
0.0 100.0 20.1
1.0 104.0 14.2
3.0 105.0 11.2
5.0 111.0 3.3
7.0 116.0 -3.6
9.0 117.0 -6.5

//how do I get the same numbers into a new 2D array as follows:
[[0.0,100.0,20.1],
 [1.0,104.0,14.2],
 [3.0,105.0,11.2],
 [5.0,111.0,3.3],
 [7.0,116.0,-3.6],
 [9.0,117.0,-6.5]]
```

Comment: Swift 5 is out now. Do you really need to use Swift 2 which has been obsolete for several years now?

Comment: And i think, **Swift 2.0** apps can not be submitted from app store. Minimum seems to be 3.2 i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be as simple as this,

```
var anotherArray: [[Double]] = []
for x in 0..<testArray.count {
    let result1 = Double(testArray[x][0])
    let result2 = Double(testArray[x][1] + mod[x])
    let result3 = Double(testArray[x][2] - mod[x])
    anotherArray.append([result1, result2, result3])
}
print(anotherArray)
```

Comment: This also works. Exact same output as above solution.

Comment: Note this is the LESS CPU-intensive method. Looks like it is more complex than the single line-of-code solution per @rmaddy but this actually runs quicker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map`:

```
let result = testArray.indices.map { [ testArray[$0][0], testArray[$0][1] + mod[$0], testArray[$0][2] - mod[$0] ] }
```

On a side note, your `for` block can be written as:

```
for x in testArray.indices {
    let result1 = testArray[x][0]
    let result2 = testArray[x][1] + mod[x]
    let result3 = testArray[x][2] - mod[x]
    print(result1,result2,result3)
}
```

Comment: My bad I'm running xcode 8.2.1 which shows swift 3.0.2. The indices is working fine.

Comment: I've tried both methods the simple one line of code shown here (t = testArray.indices.map { [ ..........) and the anwer per @Kamran. This answer is clever and clean but seems to bog the CPU down more. Running a 20x5 array and the computer times out with a message that the code is too complex. Works for smaller arrays.